# ExpressJS Node.js Angular Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND While Getting OAuth2 API Authorisation Token

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, oauth-2.0

I have written an angular application, which onclick of a button makes an HTTP post request to an Node/Express.js endpoint for authorisation token.

Within postman, I have done the following successfully:

1. Configured the relevant credentials for the basic OAuth2 authorisation token and getting an access token
2. I am calling a restful endpoint with a access token and creating a user on the ldap directory.

In the angular app, I have created the following key components:

1. User interface
2. AuthResponse interface
3. Auth Service
4. UI Component

Below is the logic excerpts for the Auth Service in the angular frontend app:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from  './../auth/user';
import { AuthResponse } from  './../auth/auth-response';
import { tap } from  'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from  'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  AUTH_SERVER = "http://localhost:3000";
  authSubject  =  new  BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  register(user: User): Observable<AuthResponse> {
      return this.httpClient.post<AuthResponse>(`${this.AUTH_SERVER}/register`, user).pipe(
        tap((res:  AuthResponse ) => {

          if (res.token) {
            console.log("ACCESS_TOKEN : "+ res.token.access_token);
            localStorage.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", res.token.access_token);
            localStorage.set("EXPIRES_IN", res.token.token_type);
            localStorage.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", res.token.expires_in);
            localStorage.set("EXPIRES_IN", res.token.refresh_token);
            this.authSubject.next(true);
          }
        })

      );
    }
}
```

Below is the code in the angular view component

```
  register() {
    console.log('fetching registration token');
    this.authService.register(this.user).subscribe((res) => {
      //this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
    });
  }
```

Below is the html fragment which call contains the button calling the register endpoint:

```
<div>
      <button (click)="register()" >Register</button> 
</div>
```

Below is my expressjs app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('https')
const app = express()
const  router  =  express.Router();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser  = require("body-parser")
const api_helper = require('./util/api_helper')

const port = 3000

app.use(cors());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:  false }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Welcome to Make REST API Calls to Authorisation Server In Express!');
});

router.get('/getAPIResponse', (req, res) => {
    api_helper.make_API_call('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => {
        res.json(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.send(error)
    })
})


router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Entering the server endpoint ');

  //following variables are being printed to my browser console successfully
  console.log('angular sent user name = '+req.body.username);
  console.log('angular sent password = '+req.body.password);

  var client_id = 'xxxx';
  var client_secret = 'yyyyyy';
  var auth_header = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64');

  const data = "grant_type=password&username=joe&password=joepass&client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyyyy";

  var authURI = "https://[hostname]:[port-no]/osp/a/idm/auth/oauth2/token";

  const options = {
      hostname: authURI,
      form: data,
      port: [port-no],
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-formurlencoded'
          //'Authorization': auth_header
      }
  };

  http.request(options, (res) => {
  //  const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    res.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept,Accept-Language,Content-Language,Content-Type')
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('error is ' + error);
  });

});

app.use(router);
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Node server listening on port ${port}!`))
```

The following endpoint in my nodejs app.js works:

router.get('/getTestResponse', (req, res) => {
    api_helper.make_API_call('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => {
        res.json(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.send(error)
    })
})

Its using the following helper function:

```
const request = require('request')

module.exports = {
    /*
    ** This method returns a promise
    ** which gets resolved or rejected based
    ** on the result from the API
    */
    make_API_call : function(url){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
              if (err) reject(err)
              resolve(body)
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Problem is I get the following error when I click the register button from the angular app.
But, the nodejs /register endpoint is being triggered, i.e. its logging the username and password retrieved from the request object to the console:

```
Entering the server endpoint 
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://[hostname]:[port-no]/osp/a/idm/auth/oauth2/token
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'https://[hostname]:[port-no]/osp/a/idm/auth/oauth2/token'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! registration-express-app@0.0.1 start: `node ./src/app/app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the registration-express-app@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/admin/.npm/_logs/2020-03-28T08_56_14_947Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the http.request options. Basically, the hostname: should be just hostname, not https://[hostname]:[port-no]/xxx/auth/oauth2/token!
Then use the path attribute for the remainder of the endpoint URI i.e./xxx/auth/oauth2/token .

That progressed things, but I am now getting another error "Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain"
I will close this question on that note, to ensure others can gain from my experience.
Giving back to the community.

See some nice reference below:

https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/https/